# error date period PHP

Tags: php, date, intervals

i have these code,

```
  $end = strtotime ('last day of previous month') ;
  $start = strtotime ("-1 year +1 day", $end) ;

    $new ['first'] =  date ('Y-m-d',$start) ;
    $new ['last'] = date ('Y-m-d',$end) ;

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString ('1 month') ;
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end) ;

    foreach ($periods as $period) {
      print_r($period -> date_format('Y-m')) ; echo "<br>";
    }
```

but, I have returned by this message:

An uncaught Exception was encountered

> Type: Exception
>
> Message: DatePeriod::__construct(): This constructor accepts either
>   (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, int) OR (DateTimeInterface,
>   DateInterval, DateTime) OR (string) as arguments.

anyone can help me?

Comment: Try to change to

$period = new DatePeriod($new['first'], $interval, $new['last']) ;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have syntax error and object initialization error. Here is the correction:

```
$end = strtotime ('last day of previous month') ;
$start = strtotime ("-1 year +1 day", $end) ;
$new['first'] =  date ('Y-m-d', $start) ;
$new['last'] = date ('Y-m-d', $end) ;

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString ('1 months') ;

$periods = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($new['first']), $interval, new DateTime($new['last'])) ;

foreach ($periods as $period) {
    print_r($period->format('Y-m')) ; echo "<br>";
}
```

Problem 1: `DatePeriod` constructor accepts DateTime object. Please check manual http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

Problem 2: you need `$periods`variable as you used in foreach

Answer (score 0):

Your error results from trying to pass in an `int` where there should be a `DateTimeInterface`.

If we look at the construct from the `DateTime` class we see the following:

```
/**
 * @param DateTimeInterface $start
 * @param DateInterval $interval
 * @param DateTimeInterface $end
 * @param int $options Can be set to DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE.
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php
 * @since 5.3.0
 */
public function __construct (DateTimeInterface $start, DateInterval $interval, DateTimeInterface $end, $options=0) {}
```

---

This can be very easily solved by converting to the right data types:

```
$end = strtotime ('last day of previous month') ;
$start = strtotime ("-1 year", $end) ;

$new ['first'] =  date ('Y-m-d',$start) ;
$new ['last'] = date ('Y-m-d',$end) ;

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString ('1 month') ;
$period = new DatePeriod((new DateTime())->setTimestamp($start), $interval, (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($end)) ;
```

Which will successfully satisfy the type hint present in `DatePeriod` class.

---

This is the relevant part:

```
(new DateTime())->setTimestamp($start)
```

---

You can also check out the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.dateperiod.php) class in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here `$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end) ;`

the Construtor for `DatePeriod` is :

```
public DatePeriod::__construct ( DateTimeInterface $start , DateInterval $interval , int $recurrences [, int $options ] )
```

ie. it expect the DateTimeInterface type object and you are passing a date object to it. also you have created a DatePeriod object of named $period and trying to use $periods in foreach loop..(seems like typo)
even though you have answers here...here is something that i tried and worked for me.

```
<?php
        $end = strtotime ('last day of previous month') ;
        $start = strtotime ("-1 year +1 day", $end) ;

        $new ['first'] =  date ('Y-m-d',$start) ;
        $new ['last'] = date ('Y-m-d',$end) ;

        $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString ('1 month') ;
        $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$start)), $interval, $end) ;

        foreach ($period as $pd) {
            print_r(date_format($pd,'Y-m')); echo "<br/>";
        }
    ?>
```